# Where do I stand in the reputation distribution?

Tags: discussion, reputation

As I've started answering questions on Stack Overflow, the question pops into my mind: Where do I stand?  The reward system is addicting. There are countless users with a reputation of 1 or 2, and of course the superstars with 100,000+ reputation.  But is there a place I can go to see where I (or those with my same reputation) stand in the overall reputation distribution?  I've seen [stats](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html) but that doesn't seem to show what I'm looking for.

Comment: You mean like this https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

About two thirds of Users have a reputation of 1.

You currently have 96 reputation. This puts you above (or at the same level as) 92% of site users.

This information is accessible in [stack exchange data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/676644/rep-distribution#resultSets)

[image]

Comment: I love this graph. You should do it again, and ignore all the users below 100. I would argue if you don't even get to 100, then you aren't really playing the game. :)  In which case TomServo will be closer to 89th percentile?

Comment: @JohnHenckel I'd say it would be better to eliminate everyone not greater than 10 or 20, they are truly not playing "the game".  But it's not as bleak as that, because even if you're at 10 you at least contributed, which means you're automatically in a higher class of those who teach. If hiring, you'd want people who teach, as they're team players and make other coders better around them-- immeasurable value.

Answer (score 4):

This page shows rank:

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2017-01-01?sort=rankchange

Comment: Searching for JLH doesn't return the OP here though. Looks like you need 200 rep before you show up there.

Comment: @MartinSmith it does say so in the bottom right corner: "* users with less than 200 reputation are not tracked in the leagues"